# How to write a javascript regex to check for a single character that can be followed by anything but 3 specific characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, client-side

I am trying to parse a long string like this:

```
asfdasdlfkjdk&dasfdas&amp;asdfkjsdakldfjk&
```

to produce the following output:

```
asfdasdlfkjdk&amp;dasfdas&amp;asdfkjsdakldfjk&amp;
```

basically i just need to replace any ampersand that isn't encoded into a string value that is encoded :

```
& => &amp;
```

i could do this with a string replace, but i would risk having values like this:

```
&amp;amp;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:

```
var result = orig.replace(/&(?!amp;)/g, '&amp;');
```

where the `(?!...)` notation denotes a [zero-width negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), meaning "this position is not followed by `...`.

Alternatively, in your case you could write:

```
var result = orig.replace(/&(?:amp;)?/g, '&amp;');
```

which will replace either `&amp;` or `&` with `&amp;`.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way (global change then fix exceptions):

```
string.replace(/&/g,"&amp;").replace(/&amp;amp;/g,"&amp;");
```

Or:

```
string.replace(/&amp;/g,"&").replace(/&/g,"&amp;");
```

Comment: What if the string is `"amp;amp;"`?

Comment: @musically_ut right! I edited the first option to address your comment.